# GNU Radio and wildlife tracking

Tags: linux, signal-processing, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, software-defined-radio

I work with wildlife radio transmitters and I would like to build something that will listen for these signals and keep track of what it has heard. The signal is a tone that is transmitted 60 times per minute normally, or 120 if a motion sensor indicates the animal has died.

My plan is to use GNU Radio to listen and convert the signal into some type of matrix that is saved to file, and then analyzed in a second program. Is there a way to get vectors of signal strength at 500 Hz intervals across a few megahertz, and put them together into a matrix?

The secondary program would interpret this output and find the wildlife transmitters and record their pulse rates. The idea would be to get an new file every 10 seconds or so from GNU Radio, and process it with the second program as it is received.

I have been trying to use the file sink block in GNU Radio, and realized that it is in binary. Also not sure what exactly what it contains.

Any suggested approaches on how I should do this would be appreciated!

Comment: I think the solution depends strongly on your receiver device.  You need to explain more about it.

Comment: @shellter I think this is a very implementation-specific question, although I agree that OP might be missing some DSP aspects here; I think it *is* on-topic here, but OP should ask another question about how to estimate power in a band on dsp.se.

Comment: @MarcusMüller : Good stuff below (and way over my head). Happy to withdraw my objection. Good luck to all.

Comment: I'm kind of taking this one step at a time. Right now I'm just using a simulated signal source while I work on understanding how to get the data to where I can work on it. Once I have that figured out I have a low cost RTL USB antenna and and actual transmitters to use while I write some code to recognize the signals. Then once that is all working I will switch to a yagi designed for the transmitters. Not what the best way to attach it to the computer will be. Perhaps just use the USB adapter that the RTL antenna came with.

Comment: @John: Ah, ok, you have an RTL dongle. Yes, that should work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My plan is to use GNU Radio to listen and convert the signal

Well, you will need hardware to do that; what kind of SDR device do you have in mind?

In the following, I'll assume you're really using the classical SDR approach of getting a device that gives you raw I & Q samples.

> If there were a way to get vectors of signal strength at 500 Hz intervals across a few megahertz, and put them together into a matrix.

Slow down on the matrix, let's focus on getting power from equidistant frequencies:

That is pretty much a power spectral density (PSD) estimator. The easiest, probably fastest and classical approach would simply be taking the magnitude square of an FFT of your input signal.

GNU Radio Companion has the *log-power FFT* block, which, for an input time sample stream, will give you `FFT size` vectors (which should then obviously be = sample rate / 500 Hz) at a `Frame rate` rate; for example:

[image: Flow Graph from GNU Radio Companion]

Saving these vectors to a file would be sufficient, because:

> I have been trying to use the file sink block in GNU, and realized that it is in binary. Also not sure what exactly what it contains.

It's the numbers, raw, contiguous, as they would be in memory. There's always some misconceptions about that, so there's an [FAQ entry](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/FAQ#What-is-the-file-format-of-a-file_sink-How-can-I-read-files-produced-by-a-file-sink) on that; citing that:

> All files are in pure binary format. Just bits. That’s it. A floating point data stream is saved as 32 bits in the file, one after the other. A complex signal has 32 bits for the real part and 32 bits for the imaginary part. Reading back a complex number means reading in 32 bits, saving that to the real part of a complex data structure, and then reading in the next 32 bits as the imaginary part of the data structure. And just keep reading the data.

So, one method to use would just be using Python/`numpy`, using `numpy.fromfile(file, dtype=numpy.float32)`, and then `numpy.reshape((rows,cols))` to bring the resulting 1D array of floats into the matrix shape you want.

Regarding your file naming wishes: That's a pretty algorithmic problem (and why I think this question is very on-topic here). You will probably not get around writing a bit of code yourself; that's really not that hard to do. A Python block that always takes `n` vectors and writes them to a file with a name matching the current time will totally do for your application.

Writing blocks is one of the most fun things you can do in GNU Radio; I think it is very worth pointing you to the [GNU Radio Guided Tutorials](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Guided_Tutorials). They are quite fun to read, and you can follow the examples without hardware! It's recommendable to do them in order.

---

A few comments:

1. The FFT is a good, easy to use, fast, efficient estimator.
   However, depending on the characteristics of your trackers, using a filterbank would probably outperform it with respect to accuracy/error probability. As soon as you feel comfortable with GNU Radio and DSP, have a look at the Polyphase Filter Banks that come with GNU Radio. They allow you to take one "good" low pass filter to select a single channel, and replicate them in even intervals.
2. I'm very used to *not* doing the analysis outside of GNU Radio.
   I find it much easier to write another python block that just takes the samples that come out of an estimator (in your case, e.g. the log power FFT) and do useful things with them, and connecting the output of that e.g. to a Qt GUI frequency sink, than let's say taking measurement samples and push them trough Matlab or R.
   Most of the time, I'm generating a Python file that runs my measurement flow graph, which saves its results in a vector sink. From that Python file, after the flowgraph has completed running, I use numpy to do my own offline analysis immediately.
   Comes with the advantage of being instantaneously repeatable!

---

Final remarks: You say you already have an SDR device (an RTL dongle). That's great!

Attach it to your PC; use librtl/gr-osmosdr by using `osmocom -s 1e6 -W` to get 1 MHz of bandwidth "displayed"; tune to your transmitter's frequency and watch the spectrum. You'll learn a lot!

If you don't have all that software yet: Just download and boot the [GNU Radio live SDR environment](https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/GNURadioLiveDVD). Plug and play!

In GNU Radio Companion, just replace the *UHD: USRP Source* by the osmocom source (which can talk to RTL dongles).

Comment: Yes analysis inside GNU Radio sounds great. I didn't realize that I could just write my own blocks.

Comment: I want to do exactly this. But at a high level - how do I go from GNU radio "block" setup to a Java program?

Comment: @AlGrant please don't ask new questions in the comments. Open up a new question post. Make sure it's specific and not too broad!

Comment: Hopefully not flagged for being duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77492511/gnu-radio-and-wildlife-dsp

Answer (score 1):

I'd do some research on the transmitters. Look for web pages and (especially) find the FCC ID from a transmitter and look it up on the [FCC](https://fccid.io) website. Then we can help more.

WHere can we find trackers? Getting a recording of the signal for use at home would be handy.

Comment: I have many of these transmitters available to experiment with. Here is a video of what it sounds like and the receiver that is normally used. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xnmf_4RA7SA

Comment: https://wildlifematerials.com/research/faq.php?q=2 So it looks like they use 1 MHZ slice of spectrum in 1000 Hz steps at 219 MHz. Make sense guys?

Comment: One small project with not too many transmitters might stay in a 1 MHZ slice, but I have hundreds of transmitters and typically use 4 MHZ. It is normal to keep 10 kHz spacing between transmitters in order minimize interference if the transmitters are near each other. The transmitters are available in 1 kHz steps. The actual strongest signal might be up to 1500 Hz off of the label, when trying to find a faint signal its beneficial to know the exact actual frequency and set your tuner to it.