# GNU Radio and Wildlife DSP

Tags: signal-processing, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I have a RTL-SDR and want to count the numbers of beeps per minute for a wildlife tracker around 150Mhz. There is no information encoded/modulated in the beeps - it all comes down to beeps per minute - or time between beeps.

Similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964742/gnu-radio-and-wildlife-tracking) and [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/50103/checking-for-vhf-pulse-with-sdr-and-python). The answer there talks about power spectral density (PSD) estimator for equidistant frequencies - not sure what that means as I only am dealing with one frequency at a time.

The basic idea is that a unmodulated signal is output at for example 20 beats per minute (bpm) alive, 50 beats per minute dead, 80 beats per minute means pregnant etc.

The beeps are short in duration, and in essence I presume this means using GNU to :

```
a) method determine the start of a beep;
b) time until next beep
c) signal strength of received beep
```

I have not done any DSP since the basic stuff I did many years ago, but have run through the GNU radio tutorials to get up and running.

We have 10 animals we are tracking, so ideally it would be good to pass in an array of 10 frequencies, and log the bpm to a csv file with time/date stamp once per hour for each of the 10 frequencies.

Enviroment:
OS: Windows 10
Hardware: RTL-SDR

I hope this is enough detail. I can update any missing information.

A sample baseband recording is [here](https://geekhelp-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/al_geekhelp_co_nz/Ef73ZhPenKtChsqMPM4Vh9gB-AeaLbyFcH6zvlP653d0FQ?e=6QgaIG).

Comment: Do you expect somebody to go and implement the whole software for you? This forum is for Q&A, if you have questions about some specific piece of code, then show the code and ask